# Jenkins Pipeline - If/Else Statement with Matrix Name vars

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I dont know why i cant get this to work but could use some help.

I have a Jenkins pipeline with a matrix defined, one of the axis is defined as OS for windows or linux.

In one of my stage's i want to call different things if the OS is linux or windows, but i keep getting an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, acceptGitLabMR, addEmbeddableBadgeConfiguration, addGitLabMRComment,
```

My Matrix is defined like this

```
matrix {
    agent { 
        label ("${DUT} && ${OS}")
    }
    axes {
        axis {
            name 'BUILD_TYPE'
            values 'Internal'
        }
        axis {
            name 'DUT'
            values 'DUT'
        }
        axis {
            name 'OS'
            values 'windows', 'linux'
        }
    }
```

And my stage is defined like this

```
stage ("Cleaning System") {
    steps {
        script {
            if (${OS} == 'windows') {
                stage ('Cleaning Up Windows System') {
                    echo "WINDOWS CLEAN"
                }
            }
            if (${OS} == 'linux') {
                stage ('Cleaning Up Linux System') {
                    echo "LINUX CLEAN"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like it doesnt know the ${var} syntax inside a script block?  Or what am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont' require a `$` in the comparison:
It should be :

```
if (OS == 'windows') {
  ...
}
if (OS == 'linux') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It does, thanks.  Can you briefly describe the reasoning behind why its OS and not ${OS} like in other stages?  Is it because its wrapped in a script?

Comment: @user1024792 ou just need ``$`` when you would be passing in a string .``"`` or ``'``